# Laravel worktable user specific not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to build an web application where an employee can review his working times. This works until now, showing you a list of all employees and their workshifts.

This is nice and all, but we would like to have that only available to the admins. The regular Employees should only have access to their personal records.

I personally am running out of options considering you cannot place an if inside the foreach loop. So please let me know if it is possible to do something in the context of:

```
IF Auth::user()->admin == 1{

//Show all employee records

} ELSE

//Show only logged in employee's record
```

*I highly advice you look at the example as to get a better idea of what I am trying to build.*

**HOUR CONTROLLER**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Hour;
use App\User;

class HoursController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index()
{
    $hours = Hour::all();
    return view('hour.index', compact('hours', 'specificQuery'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $users = User::pluck('name','id');
    $huidigeWeek = date("W");
    $huidigeDag = date("l");

    return view('hour.create', compact('users', 'huidigeWeek', 'huidigeDag'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $hour = new Hour;
    $hour->fill($request->all());
    $hour->save();

    return redirect('/uren')->with('success');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $hour = Hour::all()->find($id);
    return view('hour.show', compact('hour'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    $hour = Hour::all()->find($id);
    return view('hour.edit', compact('hour','user'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $hour = Hour::all()->find($id);
    $hour->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/uren/' . $id)->with('succes');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $hour = Hour::all()->find($id);
    $hour->delete();
    return redirect('/uren/')->with('succes');
}
}
```

**INDEX VIEW**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<table class="display table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive dynamic-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Werknemer</th>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Dag</th>
            <th>Aantal uren</th>
            <th>Toelichting</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <br>
    @if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
    @foreach($hours as $hour)
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-url="/uren/{{ $hour->id }}">
        <td>{{ $hour->User->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->weeknummer }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->dag }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->uren }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->toelichting }}</td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endif
    </tbody>

</table>
<br>
<a href="/home">Keer terug naar het dashboard.</a>
</div>
@endsection
```

**HOUR DATABASE MODEL**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Hour extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'werknemer_id', 'weeknummer', 'dag', 'uren', 'toelichting',
];

public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'werknemer_id');
}
}
```

**CURRENT EXAMPLE OF ADMIN VIEW**

https://gyazo.com/fa75c6eb28da26d1adbc451e999dc853

Comment: are you storing user_id in database table?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the Hour model. I added it now, so please review it as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution you can try is change your `index()` method little bit,

```
public function index()
{
    $allHours = [];
    $memberSpecificHours = [];

    if(Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
        $allHours = Hour::all();
    } else {
        $memberSpecificHours = Hour::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }

    return view('hour.index', compact('allHours', 'memberSpecificHours', 'specificQuery'));
}
```

then update your view to this,

```
@if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
    @foreach($allHours as $hour)
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-url="/uren/{{ $hour->id }}">
        <td>{{ $hour->User->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->weeknummer }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->dag }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->uren }}</td>
        <td>{{ $hour->toelichting }}</td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
        @foreach($memberSpecificHours as $hour)
        <tr class="clickable-row" data-url="/uren/{{ $hour->id }}">
            <td>{{ $hour->User->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->weeknummer }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->dag }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->uren }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->toelichting }}</td>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </tr>
        @endforeach
@endif
```

This should work

Comment: It returns https://gyazo.com/0ab557a7b5007ce577f0b90dc6152f4b but the Auth is there; https://gyazo.com/2bff6a1e942e04df16d71c0b6eccf0e0 . Help?

Comment: You need to import the `Auth` facade. alternatively you can use `\Auth::user()->admin`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!